# is there a way to customize a reference area shape in recharts?

Tags: recharts

I'm basically trying to replicate this:
[chart.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t4sa.gif)

I have tried an area chart - [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/daq6hx17/1/) -  and a scatter chart with a reference area but not getting the results, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
    <AreaChart width={600} height={400} data={data}
                margin={{top: 10, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0}}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
            <XAxis dataKey="name" domain={[0, "auto"]}/>
            <YAxis  dataKey="hct"/>
            <Tooltip/>
            <Area type='monotone' dataKey='lct' stackId="1" stroke='green' fill='none' />        
            <Area type='monotone' dataKey='hct' stackId="1" stroke='green' fill='none' />
            <Area type='monotone' dataKey='pv' stackId="1" stroke='none' fill='none' />
            <ReferenceDot  r={5} fill="red" stroke="black" y={5600} x={147} alwaysShow={true} />
   </AreaChart>
```

Thanks